# Could "fortunes" mean "population" for some situations?

Tags: meaning

[From a tutorial](https://help.flourish.studio/article/44-bar-chart-race-an-overview)

> Use this template to visualize the changing **fortunes** of people or groups in competition with each other, like political candidates, countries' populations or football teams.

[image]

The first bar in the plot represents China urban **population** for 2017.

I searched all the meanings [in the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fortune?q=fortunes) but didn't find an item similar to "population".

Could "fortunes" mean "population" for some situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what they mean here is similar to "fates" or "outcomes"... the *fortunes* of groups of people are what happens to the people in those groups in the long term.

In a similar usage, a *fortune teller* is someone who tries to predict your fortune - your future.

Comment: Thank you. For this particular situation, it means the trends of urban population in those countries, right?

Comment: Yes - they have graphed population, just to give an example of how to use the template.  A template is a basic pattern.  This is a graph template.  You could use it to graph other outcomes - as they suggest, votes or sports scores.  All of these outcomes can be referred to as "fortunes" - how fortunate they were, in a sense.